# Kubuntu custom shortcuts doesn't work

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, plasma-5

I am using Kubuntu 18.04 with KDE Plasma 5.12.6. When I add some custom shortcut keys from the settings, they work for a 1-2 minutes then suddenly stop. Just nothing happens. Then I have to go back to settings and reapply them but again - they work just for a while. Is there a way to fix this bug?

I made these shortcut keys:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> to run command `killall plasmashell`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to run command `konsole`

Edit: I think I found what is the reason. Suddenly some apps disappear from the system tray in the panel. And then I am unable to use the custom shortcuts. When I add new panel or restart the plasmashell they are working again. Strange.

Comment: @DKBose yeah, very odd. Some apps constantly disappear and appear in the panel.

Comment: Yes, clean install.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps, you could install `inxi` and then add the output of `inxi -Fxz` to your question in case there's something about your system specs that may provide a clue.